# Meteor + Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I have been trying to use bootstrap 3 with Meteor, however bootstrap works but the Glyphicons are not. When the file with the icons imports it shows the following error:

```
Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type     text/html:"http://localhost:3000/client/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff".
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've placed this file in the wrong place. All files that should be served by Meteor as a separate entities should be placed inside `/public` directory.

---

When Meteor server gets a path, it first checks whether there is a matching file in `/public`. If there is one, it is served. Otherwise Meteor loads itself to the client as a HTML file, and process the path afterwards in the client-side router of choice.

In your case, you're trying to access file that's in the `/client` dir, not in the `/public` one, so the second scenario happens. As a result, browser gets HTML file with Meteor code where it supposed to receive a font.

To solve this move the font to a place like `/public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff` and then access via `/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff` everywhere where it's used in Bootstrap's CSSes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked. I'm still a Meteor newbie.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my bootstrap3 own package structure, which works as expected for me :

```
bootstrap3
|-> dist (bootstrap3 directory containint js/, css/ and fonts/)
|-> bootstrap_override.css (override fonts paths)
|-> package.js (package definition)
```

bootstrap_override.css

```
@font-face{
    font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src:url('/packages/bootstrap3/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
    src:url('/packages/bootstrap3/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/packages/bootstrap3/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/packages/bootstrap3/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('/packages/bootstrap3/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

package.js

```
Package.describe({
    summary:"bootstrap 3.0 packaged for Meteor."
});

Package.on_use(function(api){
    api.use(["jquery"],"client");
    //
    api.add_files([
        // bootstrap fonts
        "dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css", (optional bootstrap2 lookalike theme)
        // bootstrap javascript
        "dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ],"client");
    api.add_files([
        "dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot",
        "dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf",
        "dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg",
        "dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff"
    ],"client",{
        // undocumented hint : do not bundle those files along with with js/html resources
        isAsset:true
    });
    api.add_files([
        // overriding css
        "bootstrap_override.css"
    ],"client");
});
```

This package specify that the fonts are special resources that shouldn't be bundled on the client along with regular js/html, quoting core dev David Glasser "it needs to be unprocessed and separately fetchable". (see https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1357)

The bootstrap_override.css file is necessary to override the defaults relatives paths defined in bootstrap.css with our package related absolute paths.

You can alternatively also use the bootstrap-3 package from atmosphere. (https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/bootstrap-3)

Comment: I'm using the package from atmosphere (which has the same structure as you wrote here) but I get the same error as David mentioned. And this seems normal to me, as the files are indeed not in the public directory, but in the client one (in the package). Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Using Storm, I drilled into the .meteor folder > local > build > programs > web.browser > packages > twbs_bootstrap > dist > fonts to find the glyphicons libraries and I just copied them to \public\fonts.