# Bootstrap glyphicons not loading with Meteor 0.7.0.1

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fonts, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

The icons no longer render (show up as little squares), though the only change I made was updating to Meteor 0.7.0.1 from Meteor 0.7.0

I get these warnings

`Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/client/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff".
Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/client/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf".
Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/client/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg".`

I checked my directories after seeing this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848893/meteor-bootstrap-3-glyphicons-not-working), but I don't see a problem there:

```
$ ls
total 64 
drwxr-xr-x@  4 bdean  staff    136 Oct 22 14:43 private/
-rw-r--r--   1 bdean  staff     93 Dec 11 14:31 smart.json
drwxr-xr-x   3 bdean  staff    102 Dec 11 14:31 server/
drwxr-xr-x   3 bdean  staff    102 Dec 11 14:31 public/
drwxr-xr-x   5 bdean  staff    170 Dec 11 14:31 lib/
drwxr-xr-x   3 bdean  staff    102 Dec 11 14:31 collections/
drwxr-xr-x   6 bdean  staff    204 Dec 11 14:31 client/
-rw-r--r--   1 bdean  staff   2129 Dec 11 14:31 README.md
-rw-r--r--   1 bdean  staff     31 Dec 11 14:31 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x   7 bdean  staff    238 Dec 11 14:36 .meteor/
-rw-r--r--@  1 bdean  staff  12292 Dec 20 09:09 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x   6 bdean  staff    204 Dec 24 13:38 packages/
-rw-r--r--   1 bdean  staff    718 Dec 24 13:38 smart.lock
drwxr-xr-x  12 bdean  staff    408 Dec 24 14:27 .git/

$ ls public/fonts
lrwxr-xr-x  1 bdean  staff  37 Dec 11 14:31 public/fonts@ -> ../packages/bootstrap3-less/lib/fonts
$ ls -f public/fonts/
total 304
drwxr-xr-x  6 bdean  staff    204 Dec 11 14:36 ./
drwxr-xr-x  5 bdean  staff    170 Dec 11 14:36 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 bdean  staff  20290 Dec 11 14:36 glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
-rw-r--r--  1 bdean  staff  62850 Dec 11 14:36 glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
-rw-r--r--  1 bdean  staff  41236 Dec 11 14:36 glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 bdean  staff  23292 Dec 11 14:36 glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your fonts aren't referenced correctly:

Your fonts are at `/public/fonts` but they are being requested at `/client/fonts`. It looks like its an issue with the paths used for the fonts.

This is a known issue for this package, see https://github.com/eprochasson/bootstrap3-less/issues/3.

If you want to fix it you have to alter the path at https://github.com/eprochasson/bootstrap3-less/blob/master/bootstrap.lessimport#L2

So its a local path (something like this instead so it uses the files at `/public/fonts`):

```
@icon-font-path: "/fonts/";
```

Comment: Yep! It's important to remember that anything in `/public` will be accessible at `/`. E.g. `/public/images/foo.jpg` is available at `/images/foo.jpg`.

Comment: Thanks! That clears things up, except! Why would this change on the upgrade--I didn't notice anything in the release notes, and that issue is 3 months old. 3 months ago, with the setup I had earlier, everything worked peachy...

Comment: @Ben it might be because the newer version forces lots of npm modules to update themselves, perhaps less (a dependency) of bootstrap3 was updated and rebuilt the css files up afresh and created the issue. It might have been there but the new css files may not have been rebuilt